# Symfony 4 update doctrine entity with relationships

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, entity

I'm having issues to update a Doctrine entity in my application.

Here is my code

```
public function put(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    /** @var Product $entity */
    $entity = $this->findOneById($id);

    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(BaseVoter::EDIT, $entity);

    $form = $this->createForm($this->formType, $entity);

    $form->submit($data);

    if (false === $form->isValid()) {
        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'status' => 'error',
                'errors' => $this->formErrorSerializer->convertFormToArray($form),
            ],
            JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        );
    }

    /** @var Product $product */
    $product = $form->getData();
    $this->entityManager->persist($product);
}
```

My issue comes from the way the Form handles the submition of the data.
Once I run the `$form->submit()` method my persisted entity is also updated, thus I only have the new values and cannot unset my old relations.

As the entity seems to have been already persisted (in a hidden kind of way) during the `submit` process, even if I try to fetch it again from Doctrine, I still get the new values only.

Is there a nice way to do it?

Comment: Entity is __not persisted implicitly__. It is just updated by data from form. If you look into your __database__ you will see that no update happens until you call `persist`+`flush`.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not really persisted but if I ask my entity manager to `find` the entity by its ID I still get the updated one after the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you want to use the form component to do this. Here is an alternative which is more in the API spirit and give you more control on what is happening :

```
public function put(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = json_decode(
        $request->getContent(),
        true
    );

    /** @var Product $entity */
    $entity = $this->findOneById($id);
    if (null === $entity) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(BaseVoter::EDIT, $entity);

    foreach ($data as $property => $value) {
        try {
            $this->propertyAccessor->setValue($entity, $property, $value);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Handle bad property name, etc..
        }
    }

    $constraintsViolations = $this->validator->validate($entity);
    if (count($constraintsViolations) > 0) {
        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'status' => 'error',
                'errors' => $constraintsViolations,
            ],
            JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        );
    }

    $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(...);
}
```

Here I used 2 others components that are used under the hood by the form component itself :

- The Property Accessor with the **Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorInterface**
- The Validator with the **Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface**

You will have to inject this from your controller constructor.

I hope it will help you!

Also this example is not complete and you will have to improve the errors handling and the response.

Comment: Hi, I simply use the `Form` component to handle the validation of the submitted payload.
That was what seemed to be the easiest way to do it. It also nicely binds the submitted data to the entity without having to "manually" loop over all the properties.
Do you think that a normalizer / denormalizer component would be a better way to go?

Comment: Yeah the serializer could do the job to but you will have to merge your deserialize entity with your existing one with Doctrine. In my example, I replaced the serializer by the property accessor component.

Comment: I tried to implement it with your solution, but how can I use the PropertyAccessor with Doctrine relations? I do have to update oneToMany and ManyToMany relations which is my main issue here.

Comment: any thought on how I might use your solution with a Doctrine relation?